# Embed doesn't show up for slash command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a weird issue. For some reasons embed doesn't show up anymore, however it worked yesterday and I'm not entirely sure if i did something wrong or what.

Example code for interaction reply:

```
   const testEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor('Example')
        .setDescription('Some description for this embed')
        .setColor('YELLOW')
        .setTitle('Embed title');
    console.log(testEmbed);

    interaction.reply({
        content: 'Response with content!',
        embeds: [testEmbed],
        ephemeral: false
    }).catch(console.error);
```

The funniest thing is that if I comment out the content of the response, the interaction reply is completely blank.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCzbm.png

Comment: Can I know your discord.js version please ? (in your package.json file)

Comment: @MalikLahlou discord.js@13.1.0 which is the latest I suppose.

Comment: Maybe the Discord client you're using has link previews (embeds) disabled in settings? `Settings` -> `Text & Images` -> `Link Preview`

Comment: @0x464e Holy moly, thank you very much. It would take me a looong time to come up with this by myself ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [`0x464e`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813732/0x464e) mentionned, the problem wasn't on your code. You simply didn't enable link previews on your settings. You can go enable it in `Settings` -> `Text & Images` -> `Link Preview` ->

[image: Link Preview]